# Send command to launch app in iOS device using command line tool

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have been through stackOverFlow and google search's but didn't find out a proper answer to my query. I want to send a command to launch app in iOS device(connected via USB port) using command line tool (from mac system). Please don't copy paste link's in comment or in your post as I been through a **lot** of site's. I'm looking forward to a proper way along with understanding if anyone could provide.

I have seen ios-deploy, libimobiledevice and all but explanation is not given on how to install and use, i.e., test it whether it's working or not. If anyone have then please provide the same with bit of explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that you can launch an installed application off your iDevice. Instead, you can deploy then launch an application from your Mac into the connected iDevice via the command xcrun.

Comment: Edited: sorry, xcrun is just for creating .ipa file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instruments from command line, replace DEVICE_UDID, XCODE_PATH, APP_PATH, APP_NAME, TRACE_DIR and STARTING_POINT with your variables:

```
instruments -w DEVICE_UDID \
-t /Applications/XCODE_PATH.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate \
APP_PATH/APP_NAME.app \
-e UIASCRIPT STARTING_POINT.js \
-e UIARESULTSPATH TRACE_DIR \
-d TRACE_DIR
```

What I have in STARTING_POINT.js:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
```

This example simply launches app on device and then app exit. Note that the app needs proper signing.

Comment: This works for a Debug code signing only. The app exits cause the app has been signed with a distribution code signing.

Comment: The app won't necessarily exit if have more instructions in automation script, there is good reference on [UIATarget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html).

Comment: I did tried out this piece of code but faced a error of template missing (error no. is -6). Also as I understand this might require scripting for running selected app. Also what if that project doesn't exist in my path but app is installed in iDevice will it run?!

Comment: @walle84, it is probably that the template path is incorrect, would you be able to find the tracetemplate in finder? For example here is the tracetemplate on my Mac: /Applications/Xcode 5.1.1 GM/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate

Comment: It is OK if the app is already installed on device, I have the app running and controlled by a "bot" on my iPhone 5. The silver lining is that you need the **MyiOSApp.app** file, which found in build directory.

Comment: I found that Automation.tracetemplate file but then why is it saying missing template.

Comment: Hey I kinda fixed missing file issue. Now a new issue has come **Instruments Trace Error : Error Starting Recording
** Why recording. I just want to launch app and not record any thing.

Comment: Also I came across a command of xcode i.e, xcodebuild is there. So is there any xcode command for launching app into iOS device(connected via USB)

Comment: @vladof STARTING_POINT.js is script to be run but whats TRACE_DIR ? Also If I wrote a script to be run where I have to save it in  as in path or directory?

Comment: Try change TRACE_DIR to **.** (current directory), it is the directory for saving instrument trace files.

Comment: Let's start from beginning: (1) Create a dir /Users/walle84/Desktop/test/ (2) Create the walle.js file in that dir (3) Place walle.app file in that dir (4) cd to the dir (5) In the script, change STARTING_POINT.js to walle.js, change TRACE_DIR to **.**, change APP_PATH/APP_NAME.app to walle.app (6) Make sure template path is correct, device udid is correct (7) Run script

Comment: I had the same question when I worked on my automation project. As you know, Xcode has a Run button which build project, deploy app and run on device, which is nice. But I couldn't find exposed Xcode command lines to do that. Who knows, Apple might expose that in Xcode 10, right? Also are you aware that there is this ios-deploy, which runs app on jailbroken devices. (I have no experience with it)

Comment: @vladof ios-deploy and libimobiledevice are lib present for usage but I don't want to use lib. I want to know these xcode command so I could command it from ternimal or using js by instrument.

Comment: @vladof I'm also looking to access springboard and run a script onto it. Do u have any idea or info related to it.

Comment: @walle84, only thing I know is that in order to use SpringBoard, you need to jailbreak iOS, similarly ios-deploy.